# How to make a small version of my aplication properly?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm developing a Java application that displays a counter, that sums one to itself every time a pixel in a certain position is equal to a color after a certain action. The number from the counter is obtained from a text file, and gets updated on close.

I'm quite new into Swing so I'm a bit confused on how should I manage the small version of my app, which is basically the same but smaller *duh* and always on top.

Since according to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-or-bad-practice) making new JFrames is not ideal, especially since this application just shows an Integer in the end.

My thought was to make them as different classes that extend from JPanel. Is this okay? I'm a bit confused on how should I make the switch back and forth if so.

big version idea:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiFCj.png]

small version idea:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ik6qy.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why making a small JFrame would be bad. Also, you cannot display anything on a JPanel without either a JFrame or a JWindow.

My final verdict is that it would be just fine to use a small JFrame, you aren't taking performance hits or anything like that.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! is a big issue to just set the big frame not visible so I can avoid loading the counter file again?

Comment: you don't have to make a big frame you can make a really small frame that is just the size you are looking for

Comment: I don't see why not :D

Comment: Yup. Just make sure to make those JFrames visible or else you will not be able to see anything on the JFrame

Comment: Hahaha i don't know how to comment code here, one more try.
Would this be okay? http://pastebin.com/LzBLri92